# Elasticsearch highlight with multiple queries not work as expected

Tags: elasticsearch

Here I have 2 data put into elasticsearch

```
PUT /a/b/1
{
   "message": "a b"
}

PUT /a/b/2
{
   "message": "b c"
}
```

Then, I tried to get data with this query

```
GET /a/b/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "message": {}
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "_name": "query_1",
            "default_operator": "AND",
            "fields": [
              "message"
            ],
            "query": "a"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "_name": "query_2",
            "default_operator": "AND",
            "fields": [
              "message"
            ],
            "query": "b AND c"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What I have expected is, elasticsearch should **highlight "a" at data id 1** because it matchs with **query_1**, but should not highlight **"b" in data id 1** because we going to select **"b"** whenever the message include **"c"**.

This is what I expected

```
"<em>a</em> b"
```

What I actually got

```
"<em>a</em> <em>b</em>"
```

Is there anyway I can achieve what I expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, this is not possible in Elasticsearch. It will highlight all matching terms irrespective of which sub query the terms belong to. Something that comes close to what you need is [`highlight_query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html#_highlight_query) but that won't work either. The only option I can think of is querying twice - once with "query_1" and then with "query_2" and then combine the results in the client. But doing this will of course affect the scores of the document.